# Change button on click after django view

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I have this follow form using htmx, I tried writing hx-swap:innerhtml but it's just writing the response instead of the button:

```
<form id="follow-form" hx-post="{% url 'main:follow_toggle' account.id %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% if request.user in account.followers.all %}
        <button type="submit" id="follow-button" class="btn btn-secondary rounded-pill">עוקב</button>
        {% else %}
        <button type="submit" id="follow-button" class="btn btn-success rounded-pill">עקוב</button>
        {% endif %}
      </form>
```

and this view:

```
class FollowToggleView(generic.View):
    def post(self, request, account_id):
        user_to_toggle = get_object_or_404(Account, id=account_id)
        if user_to_toggle in request.user.following.all():
            request.user.unfollow(user_to_toggle)

            return HttpResponse('User unfollowed successfully')
        else:
            request.user.follow(user_to_toggle)
            return HttpResponse('User followed successfully')
```

I tried this js but it doesnt work changing the buttons classes:

```
  <script>
      const followButton = document.getElementById('follow-button');
    
      // Handle the AJAX response to update the button text and class
      document.addEventListener('htmx:afterSwap', (event) => {
        if (event.detail.target.id === 'follow-toggle') {
          const response = event.detail.xhr.response;
    
          if (response.is_following) {
            followButton.innerText = 'עוקב';
            followButton.classList.remove('btn-success');
            followButton.classList.add('btn-secondary');
          } else {
            followButton.innerText = 'עקוב';
            followButton.classList.remove('btn-secondary');
            followButton.classList.add('btn-success');
          }
        }
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Javascript code you are trying to access the follow button using `getElementById('follow-button')`. In htmx the button element might get replaced after the form submission because of page reload and also the reference to the button element might get lost.

You can modify your Javascript code so the button element will persist even after form submission:

```
document.addEventListener('htmx:afterSwap', (event) => {
  const followButton = event.target.querySelector('#follow-button');
  if (followButton) {
    const response = event.detail.xhr.response;

    if (response.is_following) {
      followButton.innerText = 'עוקב';
      followButton.classList.remove('btn-success');
      followButton.classList.add('btn-secondary');
    } else {
      followButton.innerText = 'עקוב';
      followButton.classList.remove('btn-secondary');
      followButton.classList.add('btn-success');
    }
  }
});
```

Also in your Django view you are returning an HTTP response with a plain text message instead of a JSON response that includes the `is_following` flag.